# .import error for CSV SQLite3

Tags: database, bash, shell, sqlite, applescript

I am trying to import data from a csv to a sqlite3 database with an id integer primary key. After reading [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3260825/simple-sql-lite-table-import-question), I created a temporary table to import 11 columns from a csv file.

The Data:

```
a||b||c||d||e||f||g||h||i||j||k
l||m||n||o||p||q||r||s||t||u||v
```

I tried

```
.separator "||"
.import path/to/table tableName
```

I get the following error:

```
Error: path/to/table line 1: expected 11 columns of data but found 21
```

What am I doing wrong? Should the csv file be formatted differently?

NOTE:
The list was built in AppleScript using a method similar to below. Could the echo in bash be causing a problem?

```
set delim to "||"
set myList to {"a", delim, "b", delim, "c", delim, "d", delim, "e", delim, "f", delim, "g", delim, "h", delim, "i", delim, "j", delim, "k", return, "l", delim, "m", delim, "n", delim, "o", delim, "p", delim, "q", delim, "r", delim, "s", delim, "t", delim, "u", delim, "v", return}
set myList to myList as text
set outPath to POSIX path of (path to desktop as text) & "data.csv"
do shell script "echo " & quoted form of myList & " > " & quoted form of outPath
```

Comment: What line separator are you using?

Comment: Is the line separator a sqlite3 options or are you referring to the csv file?

Comment: Asking since if the line feed would be removed, there'd be 21 fields.

Comment: Does the additional info posted above help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`return` (0x0d) by itself does not seem to be a recognised line separator for `.import` (although it may vary by version since my `.import` will also only accept single character separators)

Try replacing `return` with `linefeed` in your generating AppleScript.